# Interfacing LabView with DASGIP (help find the manual)

Tags: labview

I'm looking for a way to communicate the DAGSIP (bioreactors system from Eppendorf) with LabView, but can't find any manual. The equipment [catalog](https://www.eppendorf.com/fileadmin/General/Knowledge_base/PDF/Bioprocessing_2016_11.3.low.pdf) clearly says that it is possible, but I didn't succeed to find any, manual or guidelines (commands description, etc.) on how to organize it.

Could you point me to the manuals? Does such a document exist at all?

Comment: Sorry but I don't think this is the right place to ask this question. Have you tried the NI LabVIEW forums, or a group or site to do with laboratory information? If you get enough information to make a start with this but you hit a specific problem then that's the right time to post back here with your code and details of what isn't working.

Comment: @nekomatic: already tried, no success neither on manuals, nor guidelines. The only hint was received that bundle "DASware connect" + "LabVIEW OPC DA Client Toolkit" might be the tools in this process.